# How do I attach an existing EIP allocation to a NLB from a variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I wanted to assign a pre-defined set of EIPs for each subnet and each NLB. I have the following variables:

```
swarm_subnets = [
  "subnet-xxxx",
  "subnet-yyyy"
]
services = {
  "service1" = {
    name = "service1"
    port = "30081"
    eip_allocation = [
        "eipalloc-xxxxxx",
        "eipalloc-xxxxxx"
    ]
  },
  "service2" = {
    name = "service2"
    port = "8445"
    eip_allocation = [
        "eipalloc-xxxxxx",
        "eipalloc-xxxxxx"
    ]
  },
  "service3" = {
    name = "service3"
    port = "8444"
    eip_allocation = [
        "eipalloc-xxxxxx",
        "eipalloc-xxxxxx"
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I use the `eip_allocation` values in the dynamic block inside the aws_lb resource?

```
resource "aws_lb" "this" {
    for_each = var.services

    name               = "nlb-${each.key}-${var.environment}"
    internal           = false
    load_balancer_type = "network"
    dynamic "subnet_mapping" {
        for_each = var.swarm_subnets
        content {
            subnet_id = subnet_mapping.value
            allocation_id = <eip_allocation from the services variable>
        }
    }
    tags = local.common_tags
}
```

Comment: seen https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/for-each ?

Comment: Thanks! I got some ideas from the link you shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out eventually.

```
resource "aws_lb" "this" {
  for_each = var.services

  name               = "nlb-${each.key}-${var.environment}"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "network"
  dynamic "subnet_mapping" {
    for_each = var.swarm_subnets
    content {
      subnet_id     = subnet_mapping.value
      allocation_id = each.value.eip_allocation[index(var.swarm_subnets, subnet_mapping.value)]
    }
  }
  tags = local.common_tags
}
```

While it's looping through the values in `var.swarm_subnets`, I used [`index()`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/index_function.html) to get the index value (0 and 1 in this case) of the current subnet to get the values in `var.services.<key>.eip_allocation[]`.